# Can I check if user is a fan from a page outside of facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I've 'fan-gated' from within an iframe on a facebook tab before but I'm trying desperately to 'fan-gate' from an external website that is not within the facebook framework. We want users to "like" our client's facebook page in order to print a coupon for their product. All the different methods are making me dizzy and I feel as if I've tried each of them three times already!

You don't have to tell me HOW to do it but does anybody know if:

1. It is even POSSIBLE to do this outside of a facebook iframe?
2. What is the method I need to go with to make it happen? (Graph API, FQL, etc.)

Thanks so much in advance for any help you all can offer me.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible. Not sure what methods you've tried so far but your best bet to have functionality even remotely similar to what you're asking is to:

1. Direct (i.e., deep link) users to fan-gated tab on the client's FB page
2. Upon the user liking the page, generate a unique link that redirects the user to the page on the external website that holds the coupon.
3. Expire the link after it's been clicked so that no one else can use it. Alternatively, you can attempt to tie the unique link to a cookie on the user's machine (or something similar).
4. Modify the external website so that no one can directly link to the coupon without being routed through this fan-gating process.

Not the best user flow in the world, but it's the only way that I can think of to make it work. Trust me, I've tried. =)